# Back / Forward buttons and usability

Tags: browser, user-interface, navigation, usability, back-button

The Back and Forward buttons in a browser or browser-like application navigate *temporally* (sequence in which user navigated pages), which may not necessarily reflect the logical order of the pages.
Are there any studies that looked at how this impacts the user's mental model?
Any thoughts on how to improve usability and reduce confusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’re a couple of good lines of research looking to improve the usability of Back. One concerns making Back more like Recently Visited Pages than History:

- Greenberg S & Cockburn A (1999)
  Getting Back to Back: Alternate
  Behaviors for a Web Browser’s Back
  Button. Proceedings of the 5th Annual
  Human Factors and the Web Conference,
  Held at NIST, Gaithersburg, Maryland,
  USA, June 3th.
- Cockburn A, McKenzie B, & JasonSmith 
  M (2002) Evaluating a Temporal 
  Behaviour for Web Browsers’ Back and 
  Forward Buttons. The Eleventh 
  International World Wide Web 
  Conference Honolulu, Hawaii, USA 7-11
  May.

The other research line concerns making it easier to get to “key” pages in the Back sequence (namely, pages where navigation branches):

- Milic-Frayling N, Jones J, Rodden K,
  Smyth G, Blackwell A, & Sommerer R
  (2004) SmartBack: Supporting Users in
  Back Navigation WWW 2004, May 17-22,
  2004, New York, New York, USA.
- Orner D & MacKenzie IS (2006).
  Histree - A Hierarchical Back Menu.
  IADIS International Conference
  WWW/Internet 2006 – Volume II
- Kaasten S & Greenberg S (2001).
  Integrating Back, History and
  Bookmarks in Web Browsers. CHI 2001 •
  31 March- 5 April, 379-380.

While one might quibble over the exact designs the researchers tested, the general ideas in both lines of research are overdue for implementation in modern browsers, IMO.

It’s said that users use Back to mean “Undo.” Actually, it's more like they use it to mean "Cancel" (to revert navigation, not data entry), and sometimes they use it to mean “OK.” In any case, it causes problems particularly in rich internet applications. I’ve argued that we need to adopt a standard for Undo separate from Back if we're going to solve these problems. (http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=41).

Comment: Using the back button as an "Undo" makes sense, and usually doesn't take much code to account for. It's using it as "OK" or "I'm done changing things now" that's the real problem.

Comment: Users expect Back to go back an entire page, like OK or Close, which remove the current form or document from view, and unlike Undo, which removes a change _within_ a form/document. Back reverts _navigation_, like Close, which changes where the user is, and unlike Undo, which reverts content _edits_ without changing the user’s virtual location. Thus using Back to mean Close ("OK, I’m done") is more aligned with user expectations than using it to mean Undo.

Answer (score 7):

There was a pretty extensive 2003 study on the use of breadcrumbs (logical navigation) and whether they increased the usability over back buttons (temporal navigation). That's [here](http://psychology.wichita.edu/surl/usabilitynews/52/breadcrumb.htm).

Here's an article from Inside Firefox about how the [back button interacted with tabbed browsing](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/ben/archives/009210.html) and some UI confusion it caused.

And here's [another article](http://jrdodds.blogs.com/blog/2006/04/the_back_button.html) about how people sometimes use "Back" to mean "Undo".

Hope this helps you out!